# Find address of element in tuple of diff data types

Tags: python, list, tuples

i have tuple  `a=("Orange", [10,20,30], (24,25,66))`
when user inputs `"O"` it shows indexes right `0 0` good ,
but when i enter 10 nothing happens why? it must show `1 0`

```
a=("Orange", [10,20,30], (24,25,66))
q=input()
for i in a:
    if isinstance(i,str):
        if q in i:
            print(a.index(i),i.index(q))
    elif isinstance(i,tuple) or isinstance(i,list):
        if q in i:
            print(a.index(i),i.index(int(q)))
```

Comment: `input()`  returns a string. The string `"10"` is not in `[10,20,30]`, the integer `10` is. Nothing happens because your test `q in i` is `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter `10`, what really happens is that `q` is assigned to `"10"`, ie a string of two characters.

Your `tuple` `a` contains a list of numbers: `[10, 20, 30]`, and all of the elements are integers and none of them are strings.

You could change the `elif` to go looking for and integer like this:

```py
    ...
    elif isinstance(i,tuple) or isinstance(i,list):
        num = int(q)
        if num in i:
                print(a.index(i), i.index(num))
```

Comment: thats why im trying this   print(a.index(i),i.index(int(q))) to convert "10" to 10

Comment: Your `print()` never executes since `if q in i:` will always fail.

Comment: ohh i see now i shouldve convert it firstly thanks